# Flutter Error: The method 'setContext' isn't defined for the type 'ScreenUtil'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using flutter screenutil and The following code used to work, but it gives me this error now.

> The method 'setContext' isn't defined for the type 'ScreenUtil'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setContext'.

````
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) {
            return themeChanger;
          },
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) {
            return settingChanger;
          },
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) {
          return locationChanger;
        })
      ],
      child: Consumer2<DarkThemeProvider, AdvancedSettingsProvider>(
          builder: (context, value1, value2, child) {
        return ScreenUtilInit(
          designSize: Size(1080, 2160),
          builder: (_) => MaterialApp(
            builder: (context, widget) {
              ScreenUtil.setContext(context);
              return MediaQuery(
                  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1),
                  child: widget!);
            },
            theme: Styles.themeData(
                themeChanger.darkTheme, context, themeChanger.color),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: (widget.payload.isEmpty)
                ? Skeleton()
                : AccessedByNotifPage(
                    payload: widget.payload,
                  ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}```


[![This image shows the error](https://imgur.com/a/l9B5fDJ)
````

Answer (score 3):

Use `init()` function instead of `setContext()`
it's in the new update.

example:

```
  builder: (context, widget) {
            ScreenUtil.init(context);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade screenUtil version in pubsic.yaml to

```
flutter_screenutil: ^5.4.0
```

then flutter clean, flutter pub get and put this code in material app

```
  builder: (ctx, child) {
            ScreenUtil.setContext(ctx);
            return MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
              child: child!,
            );
          }
```